# update existing table using materialized view without deleting existing data

Tags: oracle11g

I am a newbie and have created a materialized view on a prebuilt table.

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "REPO"
 ON PREBUILT TABLE 
 WITH REDUCED PRECISION 
 AS
SELECT r.section AS section,
  hvw.id,
  hvw.resource,trunc(sysdate)
  FROM rephier r
  INNER JOIN hist hvw
  ON hvw.section  =r.sicovam
```

Whenever I refresh it deletes all the data in the table REPO and inserts new data.Is it possible in a materialized view to insert new data into table with out deleting the existing data? Tried googling it but no specfic answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I'm understanding you well - but like you said `REPO` is a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` not a `table` that you could use for `INSERTs`.

If you want to `INSERT` new rows maybe consider creating `TABLE`  instead of a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialized_views_on_prebuilt_table.htm)  are also some documentation about creating `MATERIALIZED VIEWS ON PREBUILT TABLE`